# Querying a messy table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter, transpose

I could use some help writing a query that will turn one of the weirdest tables I've encountered in something useful. So here it goes.. This is an SQL table (let's call it 'THRESHOLDS') that shows a weekly profile of a threshold. It looks like:

```
Column 1, 'Product' = X
Column 2, 'Monday_AM' = 0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2
Column 3, 'Monday_PM' = 0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2
...
Column 15, 'Sunday_PM' = 0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2
```

As you can see, there are 14 columns with threshold values, one column for each half a day. On the rows, we have Products from (let's say) A to Z, all with different threshold values for each day & hour.

What I'd like to have (based on example above) is:

```
Product     Day     Hour    Threshold
X           1       0       2
X           1       1       2
X           1       2       2
X           1       3       2
X           1       4       2
X           1       5       2
X           1       6       2
X           1       7       2
X           1       8       2
X           1       9       2
X           1       10      2
X           1       11      2
X           1       12      2
X           1       13      2
X           1       14      2
X           1       15      2
X           1       16      2
X           1       17      2
X           1       18      2
X           1       19      2
X           1       20      2
X           1       21      2
X           1       22      2
X           1       23      2
X           2       0       2
X           2       1       2
X           2       2       2
X           2       3       2
etc…
```

Are there any handy tricks I can use for this type of transformation? I'm struggling!

Thank you for your attention. :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I thought I did that when I added the 'sql' tag.

Comment: **SQL** is nothing but the **query language** - used by just about *any* of the available RDBMS systems on the market. This doesn't help us one bit ..... you need to specify whether you're using SQL Server, DB2, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, or whatever else you might be using!

Comment: Tables that aren't in 1NF are always fun. At least SQL Server, Oracle, and Postgres have (different, not standardized) ways to split a string and turn it into a temporary table, which you then can join as normal. This is why specifying your RDBMS is important.

Comment: There are numerous 'string split' functions (the one built into SQL Server 2016 and later probably isn't useful since it doesn't allow you to order the results of the split string). and that's where you should start.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot using `cross apply` and then use `string_split()` and some string manipulation:

```
select t.product, v.day,
       (left(s.value, charindex('-', s.value) - 1)  + v.offset) as hour,
       stuff(s.value, 1, charindex('-', s.value), '')
from t cross apply
     (values (t.monday_am, 1, 0), 
             (t.monday_pm, 1, 12),
             (t.tuesday_am, 2, 0),
             . . .
     ) v(str, day, offset)
     string_split(v.str, ';') s
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f924c4b99bffad80d69ca5032b9962f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is nasty, but here it is, only with two days, you get the idea, fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=55add108c905d8689854ebfb59c33052):

```
declare @t table([Product] varchar(80), [Day] int,
[Monday_AM] varchar(250),
[Monday_PM] varchar(250),
[Tuesday_AM] varchar(250),
[Tuesday_PM] varchar(250));
insert into @t values('X', 1,
    '0-12;1-22;2-32;3-42;4-52;5-62;6-72;7-82;8-92;9-102;10-112;11-122',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2')
insert into @t values('X', 2,
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2')
insert into @t values('X', 3,
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2',
    '0-2;1-2;2-2;3-2;4-2;5-2;6-2;7-2;8-2;9-2;10-2;11-2')

;WITH CTEH
AS
(
select
    Product,
    [Day],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 1) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 1) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 1) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_0],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 2) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 2) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 2) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_1],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 3) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 3) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 3) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_2],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 4) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 4) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 4) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_3],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 5) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 5) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 5) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_4],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 6) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 6) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 6) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_5],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 7) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 7) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 7) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_6],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 8) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 8) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 8) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_7],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 9) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 9) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 9) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_8],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 10) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 10) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 10) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_9],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 11) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 11) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 11) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_10],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 12) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_AM], 12) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_AM], 12) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Hour_11],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 1) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 1) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 1) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_0],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 2) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 2) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 2) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_1],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 3) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 3) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 3) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_2],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 4) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 4) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 4) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_3],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 5) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 5) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 5) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_4],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 6) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 6) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 6) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_5],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 7) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 7) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 7) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_6],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 8) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 8) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 8) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_7],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 9) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 9) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 9) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_8],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 10) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 10) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 10) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_9],
    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 11) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 11) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 11) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_10],

    Substring(';'+[Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 12) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', ';'+[Monday_PM], 12) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', ';'+[Monday_PM], 12) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Hour_11]
From @t
), CTET AS
(
    SELECT
        Product, 
        [Day],
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 1) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 1) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 1) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_0], 
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 2) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 2) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 2) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_1], 
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 3) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 3) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 3) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_2],

    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 4) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 4) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 4) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_3], 
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 5) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 5) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 5) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_4], 
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 6) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 6) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 6) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_5],

    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 7) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 7) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 7) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_6], 
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 8) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 8) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 8) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_7], 
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 9) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 9) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 9) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_8],

    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 10) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 10) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 10) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_9],  
    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 11) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM], 11) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 11) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_10],

    Substring([Monday_AM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 12) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_AM]+';', 12) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_AM], 12) - 1)) [Monday_AM_Threshold_11],

    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 1) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 1) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 1) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_0], 
    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 2) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 2) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 2) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_1], 
    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 3) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 3) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 3) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_2],

    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 4) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 4) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 4) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_3], 
    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 5) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 5) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 5) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_4], 
    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 6) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 6) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 6) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_5],

    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 7) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 7) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 7) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_6], 
    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 8) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 8) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 8) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_7], 
    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 9) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 9) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 9) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_8],

    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 10) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 10) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 10) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_9],  
    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 11) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM], 11) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 11) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_10],

    Substring([Monday_PM], dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 12) + 1, (dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos](';', [Monday_PM]+';', 12) - dbo.[fn_Nth_Pos]('-', [Monday_PM], 12) - 1)) [Monday_PM_Threshold_11]
    FROM @t
)
SELECT
    P.Product,
    P.[Day],
    --P.col_hour,
    CASE WHEN P.col_hour LIKE '%PM%' THEN P.[Hour] + 12 ELSE P.[Hour] END [Hour],
    --T.col_threshold,
    T.Threshold
FROM 
    CTEH
    UNPIVOT([Hour] for [col_hour] IN (
        [Monday_AM_Hour_0],[Monday_AM_Hour_1],[Monday_AM_Hour_2],[Monday_AM_Hour_3],[Monday_AM_Hour_4],[Monday_AM_Hour_5],[Monday_AM_Hour_6],[Monday_AM_Hour_7],[Monday_AM_Hour_8],[Monday_AM_Hour_9],[Monday_AM_Hour_10],[Monday_AM_Hour_11],
        [Monday_PM_Hour_0],[Monday_PM_Hour_1],[Monday_PM_Hour_2],[Monday_PM_Hour_3],[Monday_PM_Hour_4],[Monday_PM_Hour_5],[Monday_PM_Hour_6],[Monday_PM_Hour_7],[Monday_PM_Hour_8],[Monday_PM_Hour_9],[Monday_PM_Hour_10],[Monday_PM_Hour_11]
        )) P
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM 
            CTET
    unpivot([Threshold] FOR [col_threshold] IN (
        [Monday_AM_Threshold_0],[Monday_AM_Threshold_1],[Monday_AM_Threshold_2],[Monday_AM_Threshold_3],[Monday_AM_Threshold_4],[Monday_AM_Threshold_5],[Monday_AM_Threshold_6],[Monday_AM_Threshold_7],[Monday_AM_Threshold_8],[Monday_AM_Threshold_9],[Monday_AM_Threshold_10],[Monday_AM_Threshold_11],
        [Monday_PM_Threshold_0],[Monday_PM_Threshold_1],[Monday_PM_Threshold_2],[Monday_PM_Threshold_3],[Monday_PM_Threshold_4],[Monday_PM_Threshold_5],[Monday_PM_Threshold_6],[Monday_PM_Threshold_7],[Monday_PM_Threshold_8],[Monday_PM_Threshold_9],[Monday_PM_Threshold_10],[Monday_PM_Threshold_11]
        )) T
    ) T ON P.Product = T.Product and P.[Day] = T.[Day] and REPLACE(P.col_hour, 'Hour', 'Threshold') = T.col_threshold
```